# Is it possible to use a BIOS > 8MB in Simics yet?

Tags: simics

When I was last playing with the public release of Simics it only supported BIOS files <= 8MB. Has it been updated to allow 16MB yet? (The system I want to emulate uses 16MB BIOSes)

Answer (score -1):

The models that comes with Simics are very different so one cannot say in general that this or that is unsupported. What is the platform you are using and what was the log message you faced with BIOS size?